# Unable to add global AuthorizeFilter when using scaffolded Identity pages in ASP.Net Core MVC application

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-6.0, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I created ASP.Net Core MVC project from template with enabled Identity.

I created db from migration files using update-database command.

I was able to run application, register users and login.

I added AuthorizeFilter globally:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(o => o.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter()));
```

it still worked.

But when I scaffolded Login page using Visual Studio functionality, I wasn't able to login anymore. I was being redirecting to "infinitelly" looped url:
[image]

When I remove global AuthorizeFilter:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
```

and add it over Action:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult Index()
```

It works again.

Is there any bug preventing using scaffolded Razor Pages with global AuthorizeFilter?
Or rather I did something wrong or missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global AuthorizeFilter apply on every methods of your project that means your login method too.

I guess your login page is the page where users are redirected to when they are not logged in. so what happen is :

I'm going to login page => login page needs authorization => redirect to login page => login page needs authorization => redirect to login page...

Your login method has to accept anonymous connection cause user is not logged in yet.

Add the attribute **[AllowAnonymous]** on your login method.